# Correct syntax for applying mathematical operations to dataframes in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dataframes which represent timesteps. Each dataframe has 5 columns (x,y,G,V,I). I have 1377 of these timesteps with 128 rows in each.

What im now trying to do is add a new column (p) to each of these dataframes, the value of p is determined by some mathematical operators using the other columns. Ive tried a few methods here but im used to this syntax.

df['p']=df['G']*((df['I'])/(df['V']))

which wouldnt work here as im accessing a list.

Also my I & V column header contain the timestamp information and hence changes for every dataframe. However the V column headers start with V and the I column headers start with I. What is the easiest way to use these columns. Is there a way to use column starting with V for example. The column headers are arranged like this

x    y    G    V...   I...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The columns are always in the same location? In that case you can probably select them with `.iloc[:, 3]` to grab `V` for instance. Also any reason not to use a `dict` instead of a `list` (or just store the timestamps in some other `list`)? You could use the timestamps as keys, saving yourself the trouble of storing that information in some column headers.

Comment: The columns are always in the same location, so that should work. I actually used the list because I had is suggested to me. Its worked well up to this point and I have my data in the format I want, but im struggling on how to do the arithmetic. If I were to do it from scratch again I might do a dictionary.